# how to integrate two classes

Tags: c#, oop

i am working on a small app that mange flights, i have a class that build a flight details and class that build the passenger, now, i want to load the passengers onto a flight, how should i do it? do i need to build a higer class that inherit from this two class and make a list of that type of class(i dont think that wise oop ).or should i add a ticket prop in the passenger class that have the flight number, here is my code.

```
  public class Passenger
{
    public Passenger(string name, int passportNumber)
    {
        this.PassengerName = name;
        this.PassportNumber = passportNumber;
    }

    private string _passengerName;
    public string PassengerName
    {
        get { return _passengerName; }
        set { _passengerName = value; }
    }

    private int _passportNumber;
    public int PassportNumber
    {
        get { return _passportNumber; }
        set { _passportNumber = value; }
    }

 }

public class FlightDetails
{
    public FlightDetails(int flightNumber, string flightDestination, string planmodel)
    {
        this.FlightNumber = flightNumber;
        this.FlightDestination = flightDestination;
        this.PlanModel = planmodel;
    }

    private int _flightNumber;
    public int FlightNumber
    {
        get { return _flightNumber; }
        set { _flightNumber = value; }
    }

    private string _flightDestination;
    public string FlightDestination
    {
        get { return _flightDestination; }
        set { _flightDestination = value; }
    }

    private string _planeModel;
    public string PlanModel
    {
        get { return _planeModel; }
        set { _planeModel = value; }
    }
}
      static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<FlightDetails> flightList = new List<FlightDetails>();

        FlightDetails a = new FlightDetails(12,"france","jumbo");///create a flight

        flightList.Add(a);///  load up the flight

    }
```

Comment: Why not have a list of passengers in your Flight and add them when tickets are booked?

Comment: You cannot inherit from two _classes_.

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not supported in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample code that might work. A flight has one or more passengers, thus has a List of type Passenger. In real-life, a passenger can book multiple flights. If you want the reality, you'll have to change your model but for this situation it'll work:

```
public class Passenger
{
    public Passenger(string name, int passportNumber)
    {
        PassengerName = name;
        PassportNumber = passportNumber
    }

    public string PassengerName { get; set; }
    public int PassportNumber { get; set; }
}

public class FlightDetails
{
    public FlightDetails(int flightNumber, string flightDestination, string planmodel)
    {
        FlightNumber = flightNumber;
        FlightDestination = flightDestination;
        PlanModel = planmodel;
        Passengers = new List<Passengers>();
    }

    public int FlightNumber { get; set; }
    public string FlightDestination  { get; set; }
    public string PlanModel { get; set; }
    public List<Passenger> Passengers { get; private set; }

    public void AddPassenger(string name, int number)
    {
        int max = 2;
        int passengersNumber = Passengers.Count;

        if (passengersNumber < max)
        {
            Passengers.Add(new Passenger(name, number);
        }
    }
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var flightList = new List<FlightDetails>();
    var passengersList = new List<Passenger>();

    //Add passenger-objects to passengers-list

    var flightOne = new FlightDetails(12, "France", "Jumbo");
    flightOne.Passengers = passengersList;

    flightList.Add(a);
}
```

Here's a better solution to limit the passengers:

```
public class FlightDetails
{
    public FlightDetails(int flightNumber, string flightDestination, string planmodel)
        : this(flightNumber, flightDestination, planmodel, new List<Passenger>())
    {
    }

    public FlightDetails(int flightNumber, string flightDestination, string planmodel, List<Passenger> passengers)
    {
        FlightNumber = flightNumber;
        FlightDestination = flightDestination;
        PlanModel = planmodel;

        if(passengers.Count > 2)
            //throw exception or error
        else
            _passengers = passengers;
    }

    private List<Passenger> _passengers = new List<Passenger>();

    public int FlightNumber { get; set; }
    public string FlightDestination  { get; set; }
    public string PlanModel { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Passenger> Passengers { get { return _passengers; } }

    public void AddPassenger(string name, int number)
    {
        int max = 2;
        int passengersNumber = _passengers.Count;

        if (passengersNumber < max)
        {
            _passengers.Add(new Passenger(name, number);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this code is written without compiling. But the idea is correct normally. :)

Comment: that solutaion create a diffrent kind of issue by exposing the passenger list, lets say i want to limit the list to 2 passengers only, so i made a functio for it, but doesnt working :( , here is my code: i update in your answer code

Comment: If your edit funamentaly change the way the code works I would recommend you create your own answer

Comment: If you want to limit the number of passengers in a list, you make the setter of the list private. This way no-one can assign a new list to the property. For the non-working code: check the edited answer.

Comment: But the problem remains because someone can always do: flightDetails.Passengers.Add(...); and get around the AddPassenger-method. You could make the list completely private and fill it through the constructor. Then make a property which only returns an IEnumerable<Passenger>.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't create a class that inherits from both other classes because multiply inheritance is not allowed in C#.

You can use aggregation, something like this:

```
public class FlightDetails
{
   // ...
}

public class Passenger
{
   // ...
}

public class Flight
{
    public FlightDetails { get; private set; }
    public List<Passenger> Passengers { get; private set; }

    public Flight(FlightDetails details)
    {
        FlightDetails = details;
        Passengers = new List<Passenger>();
    }

    public AddPassenger(Passenger p)
    {
        // check for ticket and so on..

        Passengers.Add(p);
    }
}
```

You can read more about aggregation here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation

Note that in this example for simplicity i used List but actually you need to limit access to this array (because otherwise i can do something like this: Flight.Passengers.Add(p) instead of Flight.AddPassenger(p)) so good idea will be use ReadOnlyCollection as public interface to this list.

Comment: +1 for the tip on ReadOnlyCollection, did not think about that :D

Answer (score 1):

In logical way, relation between FlightDetail to Passenger is OneToMany. One FlightDetail can have multiple Passenger which is can be written as below. FlightDetail and Passenger should be have any common inheritance hierarchy because they are don't have any common attribute or behaviour.

```
 public class FlightDetails
 {
        private List<Passenger> passengerList;
        public void addPassenger(Passenger p){
            if(passengerList == null){
 passengerList = new ArrayList<Passenger>();

    }
    passengerList.add(p);
            }

    public List<Passenger> getPassengerList(){
    return passengerList;
    }
    //... your other detail
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a FlightDetails property to your Passenger class. That's easier than making a List with PassportNumber as index. But, it's easier to iterate FlightDetails using List, than accessing it through Passenger.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on how you want to access and store the relations.

It might be a good idea to read about the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) which actually has a nice solution for travelling between parent-child relations, even though the pattern has another purpose.